# Separating words joined by a period using regex

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I scrapped a pdf file into text. However, sometimes two sentences are joined by the period, for example, `... are attended **to.In** fact ...'.
I want to write a re.sub() code that will separate the two sentences. I tried myself, but I haven't succeeded. I can find the bad periods using

```
re.'findall('\w+?\.\w+', text).
```

However, if i try to use something like

```
re.sub('\w+?\.\w+', '\w+?\.\s\w+', text)
```

I  get the error 'bad escape /w at position 2'
Any advice on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you `split('.')`, then `.strip`, and then `'. '.join(...)`?

Comment: See if [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##NYyxCgIxEAX7fMWSKgFvQa0tLP0FL4dEb8UDTcLmXaE/HwNiNzDDlDceOe1bW14lK0jFGEjFpULpQJaZKapQBCTNMhMynxLd4w3UnTVGpa5P9FaF63p1at0Yh88U2LvxOJwnbzdkQ9hSCLuO/7s3RZcEcr@Bb@0L) helps.

Comment: See [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). The second argument of ```re.sub()``` is the replacement. You can use either subgroups or non-capturing groups. For the former, use parentheses in the patttern and use ```\number``` in the replacement, such as ```'\\1'```.

Comment: using split('.'), then   '. '.join(...) worked. thanks